# how to get future today to future calculate with days date in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to calulate Future date.
Today date is : 2015-09-05
if day is 120, then what will be the, future date.

I was creating Program in php, which user pay Online, 
We will give validity date by  120days from paid amount date.
Then what will be the validity date.

I will accept that person answer me correct answer 1st

Comment: What's this got to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will get you the date 120 days into the future:

```
strtotime("+120 days");
```

The strtotime function also takes a second parameter, which can be used if you want to add 120 days to a specific date instead of to the current date.

See the [official documentation](http://php.net/strtotime) for more information.

Comment: how will you explain, i was not getting

Comment: What do you want me to explain? There's not much to it.

Comment: take today date, and 120days then what date will in future, please give me code

Comment: That's exactly what that call I've given you does. Have you actually tried it yet?

Comment: Yes, which is the Unix time 120 days from now, just like it says in the documentation I've linked you. If you want a different format use the `date` function.

Comment: simple i want this is today date 2015-09-05, and validity days is 120, then what date will be in future, for example 2015-12-05, how to calculate

Answer (score 0):

$expirydate = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime('+120 days'));

Answer (score 0):

'time()' will give you unix timestamp (miliseconds elapsed since 1.1.1970).

120 days in miliseconds can be calculated like this '120*24*60*60'.

You can get current date by 'date($format)' and then add offset to it 'date($format, $offset)'.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

$future = time() + (120*24*60*60);
$format = "Y-m-d";

$now = date($format);
$future_date = date($format, $future);
?>
```

You can also check similar example  [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)